# Elements in crossed product $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, dynamical-systems, c-star-algebras, cross-product

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $G$ be a discrete group. I am quite confused about the definition of the reduced crossed product $A\rtimes_r G$ and the  full crossed product $A\rtimes G$.

What are the form of elements in reduced crossed product and full crossed product. Do they have explicit expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with nearly all constructions for building new $C^*$-algebras out of old ones, there is not an explicit representation of *every* element of $A\rtimes_rG$ and $A\rtimes G$.  But (again, as with nearly all constructions) there is a dense $*$-subalgebra where elements have an explicit form, and most calculations can be done in this subalgebra.

Let $\alpha:G\to\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ denote the action of $G$ on $A$ (we typically write $\alpha_g=\alpha(g)$ to simplify notation).  Let $C_c(G,A)$ denote the space of all functions $G\to A$ with finite support.  Elements of $C_c(G,A)$ can be written as formal sums $\sum_{g\in G}a_gg$, where $a_g\in A$.  This is made into a $*$-algebra in the following way:  for $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, $a=\sum_{g\in G}a_gg,b=\sum_{h\in G}b_hh\in C_c(G,A)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\lambda a&=\sum_{g\in G}(\lambda a_g)g,\\
a+b&=\sum_{g\in G}(a_g+b_g)g,\\
a\cdot b&=\sum_{g\in G}\left(\sum_{h\in G}a_h\alpha_h(b_{h^{-1}g})\right)g,\\
a^*&=\sum_{g\in G}\left((\alpha_g(a_{g^{-1}}^*)\right)g.
\end{align*}
(Exercise:  Check that this does make $C_c(G,A)$ into a $*$-algebra.)  Then the full and reduced crossed products $A\rtimes G$ and $A\rtimes_rG$ are defined by choosing suitable $C^*$-norms on this algebra, and taking completions.

Comment: I have a question :  $\alpha_g\in Aut(A)$ is defined as following :$\alpha_g(a)=gag^*, g\in G, a\in A$. I was puzzled: $G$ is a group, $A$ is a $C^*$-algebra, they are two different objects. The multiplication may not  be compatible.

Comment: Your first sentenced is a bit off.  $\alpha_g$ is just defined on $A$.  The product in $C_c(G,A)$ is defined so that $\alpha_g(a)=gag^*$ (it is a convolution with this formula added to interchange elements of $G$ and $A$:  $ga=\alpha_g(a)g$). As for multiplication not being compatible, consider just the formulation of $C_c(G,A)$ as functions $G\to A$ with finite support.  This is spanned by elements of the form $f_{a,g}\in C_c(G,A)$, where $f_{a,g}(g)=a$ and $f_{a,g}(h)=0$ for $h\neq g$.

Comment: (ran out of space)  The correspondence between functions $f:G\to A$ and formal sums $\sum_{g\in G}a_gg$ is given by $$\sum_{g\in G}a_g g\leftrightarrow \sum_{g\in G}f_{a_g,g}.$$

Comment: I mean that why $gag^*$ make sense? If $G$ act on G$, it is obvious that we can define the multiplication.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  This makes sense "formally" (that is, it doesn't actually make sense).  To force it to make sense, we impose the rule $gag^*=\alpha_g(a)e$ in $C_c(G,A)$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$.

Comment: I feel more confused. $\alpha_g(a)\in A$, can the element of $A$ multiply elements of $G$?

Comment: Please read my first two comments (consider them as one long comment).  Literally, no, products of elements of $A$ and $G$ makes no sense.  But we use the notation $\sum_ga_gg$ to make the formulas cleaner (to some people's eyes).

Comment: Consider, as an example, the group algebra $\mathbb CG$.  Does $(1+i)g$ make sense? No.  To be completely precise, we should consider $\mathbb CG$ as $C_c(G)$.  But we use formal sums $\sum_g\lambda_gg$ to make some formulas easier to understand.

Comment: Well, in the above statement, you mentioned that $gag^*=\alpha_g(a)e \in C_c(G,A)$,  but $\alpha_g\in Aut(A), \alpha_g(a)=gag^*\in A$?

Comment: As $G$ is discrete, there is a natural inclusion $A\hookrightarrow C_c(G,A)$ by $a\mapsto ae$.  If you don't see the $e$ in some reference, it's an abuse of notation.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and time.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm sorry if this is confusing, it certainly takes time getting used to the crossed product construction.  Just toy around with these algebras until you get a feel for how they behave.